# Как правильно получить все комбинации чисел в Python

Tags: python, комбинаторика

Есть код:

```
import itertools

for i in itertools.combinations_with_replacement('0123456789', 4):
    print(''.join(i))
```

Мне нужно получить все комбинации цифр по 4 с повторениями.
Часть вывода программы:

```
0000
0001
0002
0003
0004
0005
0006
0007
0008
0009
0011
0012
0013
0014
0015
0016
0017
0018
0019
0022
0023
0024
0025
```

Скажите, почему после `0009` идет `0011`, а не `0010` ?
Также и с `0022`.

Comment: потому что код не различает 01 и 10 (разница между комбинацией и перестановкой). А в чём проблема с `for i in range(10**4):print("%04d" % i)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Потому что для вашей задачи вам нужно брать не `combinations_with_replacement`, а `product`:

```
import itertools

for i in itertools.product('0123456789', repeat=4):
    print(''.join(i))
```

Комбинации в комбинаторике не учитывают порядка элементов. Поэтому набор тех же элементов будет считаться одной и той же комбинацией, даже если элементы в другом порядке. Ваш код один раз уже напечатал комбинацию из трёх нулей и одной единицы (0001), поэтому он не будет уже печатать другие варианты этой комбинации - 0010, 0100 и 1000. Аналогично и с другими числами.

Comment: Спасибо, все ясно)